# Text selection react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have some problems with text selection in react-native:

1. How to select text across multiple text component
2. How to detect text selection
3. How to change text selection range

Example:

```
<View>
  <Text>test1</Text>
  <Text>test2</Text>
</View>
```

User should have possibility to select "test1 tes", and app should detect it and change selection to "test1 test2"?

It'll be cool if it'll works on android.

I found only https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6cd712713b1673f13510bc127ac970648f9b5eb3 but it's only inside one text block.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I can't see a way to make this in React Native.

But, if you can use a rich text editor, try this: https://github.com/HoneyBook/react-native-richtext-editor